# Getting next and previous document

Tags: mongodb

In a mongo collection I have a list of words (millions words).

```
{word:'a'}
{word:'b'}
{word:'x'}
{word:'y'}
{word:'z'}
```

I need to get lexical adjacent of a word. I am looking for most efficient method.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest using two indexes.

suppose your collection name is words

```
db.words.ensureIndex({word: 1}) // for next word queries
db.words.ensureIndex({word: -1}) // for previous word queries

//next word query
db.words.find({word: {$gt:"a"}}).sort({word: 1}).hint({word: 1}).limit(1)

//previous word query
db.words.find({word: {$lt:"b"}}).sort({word: -1}).hint({word: -1}).limit(1)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: In your case you *should* use indexes with direction. Try to insert db.words.insert({word: "aa"}), and then try to look for the previous word of 'b', you will get 'a' not 'aa'.

Comment: "When creating an index, the number associated with a key specifies the direction of the index. The options are 1 (ascending) and -1 (descending). Direction doesn’t matter for single key indexes or for random access retrieval but is important if you are doing sort queries on compound indexes." http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/

Comment: Did you _actually_ try my comment ?